# Converting comma separated values into a list using shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file which looks like this:

```
Size: 20,30,40
Frequency: 60,70,80
```

I tried using sed where I replace the , with a new line and text but then that doesn't give me my desired output

```
sed 's/,/\nSize:/g' infile > outfile
```

I expect the output to be in a list format like the following manner (each in a new line ):

```
Size1 :20 
Frequency1: 60 
Size2 :30
Frequency2:70 
Size3 :40
Frequency3:80
 Size4 :
Frequency4: 
Size5 :
Frequency5:
```

I need two extra columns as some files can have 5 sizes

Comment: Please read the description of tags you apply, you choice clearly shows you didn't. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask], in case you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F: '{ n = split($2, nums, /,/); for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) v[$1,i] = nums[i] }
           END { for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                   printf("Size%d:%s\n", i, v["Size",i])
                   printf("Frequency%d:%s\n", i, v["Frequency",i])
                 }
           }' input.txt
Size1: 20
Frequency1: 60
Size2:30
Frequency2:70
Size3:40
Frequency3:80
Size4:
Frequency4:
Size5:
Frequency5:
```

Comment: There is a spacing problem with all expect the two first, change to `-F": "` and add a space after Size/Freq.. like this `"Size%d: %s\n"` to fix it.  An idea for OP is to use `n` instead of `5` on your solution.  It will then only print the number of field needed.

Comment: @Jotne I almost put a space before the colon on the Size lines to better match OP's desired output (and maybe indent Size4...). And he specifically said he wanted the extras for a total of 5...

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution based how Shawn's post.  It stores line name in array `s`, so it will work with any number of line with data and any number of fields.

```
awk -F": " '{
    n=split($2,a,",");
    s[$1]++;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        v[$1,i]=a[i]} 
END {
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        for (j in s) 
            printf("%s%d: %s\n",j,i,v[j,i])
        }
    }' file

Frequency1: 60
Size1: 20
Frequency2: 70
Size2: 30
Frequency3: 80
Size3: 40
```